# Windows - kill a process that stays ontop of all other windows

Tags: windows, window

**Problem**:

I was in an application (Star Citizen), and after alt+tab out I got a blackscreen with my taskbar showing activity/notification on the application.

Trying to kill the application by : starting up run, or task manager, or any other window appeared but behind this "blackscreen".

Ofcourse it is a application bug but, besides restarting which I ended up doing, how else can I end/quit/crash this application.

**Tried**:

Right-click and end does nothing, alt-f4 does nothing, alt-tab to another application selects it and I can type but I have no visual of it. Only start menu shows above this application. It has full-screen selected as mode, not windowed or borderless.

*No question has been asked regarding this, thus the reason for this question, and also curiosity!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have a second screen handy, plug it in. Make sure that it's
   extending your main screen, and not duplicating it.
2. Press `ctrl+alt+delete` to bring up the Task Manager.
3. Press `Windows+Left Arrow Key` (or right, depending on your set up)
   until it shows up on the other screen.
4. Then you can use Task Manager to kill the application that's blocking your
   main screen.

I've had issues with applications that block the screen or are always on top, and this is one way that I've gotten around them by using a second screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring up the task manager by first starting it (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd>) and and then pressing<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>escape</kbd> to bring it to the front.

Comment: OP has mentioned that task manager opened behind the black screen

Comment: You're right, I must have read over that. control+shift+escape should bring the task manager to the front.